# Oracle service auto start bach file

Tags: batch-file, service

I have 6 Java services and 1 Oracle services running on my application server. Oracle service stops when RAM is full. I need a batch file to run automatically when the Oracle service stops.

But this batch file should be checked continuously. But I do not know how the batch file was created.

Windows Server Task Manager:

[image: windows server task manager]

Comment: net start OracleServiceCTGINST1

Comment: You may create a scheduled task, either a triggered one to restart the stopped service, or a task that run a batch to check service status at a certain interval.

Comment: How are you getting on with the below answer, Omer?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a task that triggers upon event, but config the event to trigger when the service stops is not easy.

Another point of view

You can set an scheduled task to run a batch script to test if the service is running. If it isn't, it will start it.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "user=username"
set "pass=p@ssword"
set "host=server_name"

set "OracleServiceTime=3"
set "OracleServiceTask=CheckOracle"
set "OracleServiceName=the_name_of_the_service"

rem schtasks /query /TN "%OracleServiceTask%" /S "%host%" >NUL 2>&1
schtasks /query /TN "%OracleServiceTask%" >NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
  rem schtasks /create /SC MINUTE /MO %OracleServiceTime% /TN "%OracleServiceTask%" /RL HIGHEST /TR "%~dpnx0" /S "%host%" /RU "%user%" /RP "%pass%" /F >NUL 2>&1
  schtasks /create /SC MINUTE /MO %OracleServiceTime% /TN "%OracleServiceTask%" /RL HIGHEST /TR "%~dpnx0" /F >NUL 2>&1
  if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 (
    rem if task couldn't be created, message user or whatever.
  )
)

tasklist /FI "imagename eq %OracleServiceName%" | find /I "RUNNING" > NUL 2>&1
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 goto :EOF

rem sc "\\%host%" start "%OracleServiceName%" > NUL 2>&1
sc start "%OracleServiceName%" > NUL 2>&1 
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
 rem if service couldn't be started, message user or whatever.
)

EndLocal
exit/B
```

This script check if the task exist, if it doesn't then create it (in this case, to run every 3 minutes)

Then test if the service is running and, if not, start it.

There are two command lines for `schtask /create` and `sc start`. If the script may run on remote system you'll need the `host user pass` syntax.